# Printing a string divided in many lists

Tags: python

I have this string:

```
string = 2p3g4p3y1g3w4w5w1w1y2w2g1p5g4g1r6g5r2r3r4r3b4b2b6r2y5y4y6w6y3p6b5b1b6p5p
```

I want to print it like this:

```
['2p', '3g', '4p', '3y', '1g', '3w']
['4w', '5w', '1w', '1y', '2w', '2g']
['1p', '5g', '4g', '1r', '6g', '5r']
['2r', '3r', '4r', '3b', '4b', '2b']
['6r', '2y', '5y', '4y', '6w', '6y']
['3p', '6b', '5b', '1b', '6p', '5p']
```

I know it is with split, but I don't know how to divide it in 6 lists

Comment: `split` splits on a delimiter; you just want to split on *position*.

Comment: Do you want 6 variable-length lists, or a variable number of 6-element lists, or is your string always exactly 72 characters long?

Comment: My string is always exactly 72 characters long

Comment: print("""['2p', '3g', '4p', '3y', '1g', '3w']
['4w', '5w', '1w', '1y', '2w', '2g']
['1p', '5g', '4g', '1r', '6g', '5r']
['2r', '3r', '4r', '3b', '4b', '2b']
['6r', '2y', '5y', '4y', '6w', '6y']
['3p', '6b', '5b', '1b', '6p', '5p']"""

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based upon dividing a list into equal size chunks
[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312443/how-do-you-split-a-list-into-evenly-sized-chunks)

```
def chunks(lst, n):
    """Yield successive n-sized chunks from lst."""
    for i in range(0, len(lst), n):
        yield lst[i:i + n]
```

**Generating Output**

```
string = '2p3g4p3y1g3w4w5w1w1y2w2g1p5g4g1r6g5r2r3r4r3b4b2b6r2y5y4y6w6y3p6b5b1b6p5p'

# Using chunks
for line in chunks(string, 12):                  # Chunk 12 elements per row
    s = ["'" + x + "'" for x in chunks(line, 2)] # chunks of two in quotes
    print(f'[{", ".join(s)}]')
```

**Output**

```
['2p', '3g', '4p', '3y', '1g', '3w']
['4w', '5w', '1w', '1y', '2w', '2g']
['1p', '5g', '4g', '1r', '6g', '5r']
['2r', '3r', '4r', '3b', '4b', '2b']
['6r', '2y', '5y', '4y', '6w', '6y']
['3p', '6b', '5b', '1b', '6p', '5p']
```

**Simpler Alternative to f-string**
(pointed out by @user120242 in comments)

```
for line in chunks(string, 12):
  print(list(chunks(line, 2)))
```

Comment: almost perfect, but I want the characters to be strings like "2p" and separated by a space

Comment: @queenbegop777--done.  Just had to change "," to ", " for the join.

Comment: @DarrylG why don't you just print(line) directly?  He's just expecting Python's normal string representation with quote delimiters

Comment: @user120242--line itself is not grouped properly.  For instance first line is: `2p3g4p3y1g3w` (i.e. no commas or spaces between groups of two elements).

Comment: print(list(chunks(line, 2))) ?

Comment: Thank you, it works! But I want to add the ' ' to each character, how can I do it?

Comment: @user120242--yes, thanks for pointing out a simpler alternative to the f-string.

Answer (score 1):

There are three pieces:

1. `re.split`, to break `string` into a list of character pairs
2. `filter`, to get rid of the empty strings our use of `re.split` will produce
3. `grouper`, a function you can find in the `itertools` documentation.

`re.split` will use the regular expression `(..)` to break `string` into a list of empty strings separated by arbitrary two-character delimiters.

```
>>> re.split('(..)', string)
['', '2p', '', '3g', '', '4p', '', '3y', '', '1g', '', '3w', '', '4w', '', '5w', '', '1w', '', '1y', '', '2w', '', '2g', '', '1p', '', '5g', '', '4g', '', '1r', '', '6g', '', '5r', '', '2r', '', '3r', '', '4r', '', '3b', '', '4b', '', '2b', '', '6r', '', '2y', '', '5y', '', '4y', '', '6w', '', '6y', '', '3p', '', '6b', '', '5b', '', '1b', '', '6p', '', '5p', '']
```

`filter(None, ...)` will remove all falsey values (i.e., empty strings) from that list. `grouper` will break the stream of 36 pairs into a list of 6-pair tuples.

```
from itertools import zip_longest
import re

string = "2p3g4p3y1g3w4w5w1w1y2w2g1p5g4g1r6g5r2r3r4r3b4b2b6r2y5y4y6w6y3p6b5b1b6p5p"

# From https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html
def grouper(iterable, n, fillvalue=None):
    "Collect data into fixed-length chunks or blocks"
    # grouper('ABCDEFG', 3, 'x') --> ABC DEF Gxx"
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return zip_longest(*args, fillvalue=fillvalue)

pairs = filter(None, re.split('(..)', string)
result = [list(x) for x in grouper(pairs, 6)]
print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be done with nested lists of comprehension:

```
output = [[string[i+j*6:i+2+j*6] for i in range(0,12,2)] for j in range(0,int(len(string)/6),2)]

#Print each list separatly:
for x in output:
    print(x)
```

**Output**

```
 ['2p', '3g', '4p', '3y', '1g', '3w']
 ['4w', '5w', '1w', '1y', '2w', '2g']
 ['1p', '5g', '4g', '1r', '6g', '5r']
 ['2r', '3r', '4r', '3b', '4b', '2b']
 ['6r', '2y', '5y', '4y', '6w', '6y']
 ['3p', '6b', '5b', '1b', '6p', '5p']
```

Comment: It prints in only one line, I don't know why

Comment: it's just a matter of proper printing, corrected the answer

Comment: It still doesn't work :(, it printed something like this:

Comment: [ ['2p', '3g', '4p', '3y', '1g', '3w'], ['4w', '5w', '1w', '1y', '2w', '2g'], ['1p', '5g', '4g', '1r', '6g', '5r']] Like in only one line

Comment: he meant print(x)